# x86 Assembly Newtons square root algorithm registers are 1#IND

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I am trying to write an assembly version of the C program below. It is meant to take the square root of 9. Everything seems to be working until the 3rd pass through my loop, and then my values for upper and lower    become 1#IND when pushed to the stack. I don't know why because it correctly prints just below the label *whileLoop*, but I get the wrong values the second time it is printed directly after the label *notAccurateEnough*, even though the values don't change between these two labels and it worked fine on the previous iterations.
Below are screenshots that show how it successfully prints once, then fails to print the second time in the same iteration.

[image: Sucessfully pring]

[image: Now it's broken]

Assembly Code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096                 
n=550
.data
    PUBLIC _sqrtX

upper REAL4 9.0
accuracy REAL4 0.00001
lower REAL4 1.0
guess REAL4 1.0
multValue REAL4 1.0
num REAL4 9.0
two DWORD 2

.code

_sqrtX  PROC

        finit   ;initialize fpu

        whileLoop:
        fld upper    ;push upper onto stack
        fld lower    ;push lower onto stack
        fsub         ;subtract upper-lower

        fld accuracy          ;push accuracy onto stack
        fcom                  ;compare accuracy with upper-lower

        fstsw ax              ;copy condition code bits to AX
        sahf                  ;shift condition code bits to flags
        jna notAccurateEnough ;jump if accuracy is greater
        jmp endnewt           ;end algorith, is less than accuracy

        notAccurateEnough:
        ;**************************
        ;************  Logic to implement:   guess = (lower + upper) / 2;
        ;**************************
        fld upper      ;push upper onto stack
        fld lower      ;push lower onto stack
        fadd           ;(lower + upper)
        fidiv two      ;divide by 2
        fstp guess     ;set guess to first stack element. guess = (lower + upper) / 2
        ;**************************

        ;**************************
        ;************  Logic to implement:  if((guess * guess) > number)
        ;**************************
        fld guess ;push guess onto stack as first element
        fld guess ;push guess onto stack again, it is now first and second element
        fmul      ;multiply first and second element
        fcom num  ;compare 9 to product of guess*guess:
        fstsw ax  ;copy condition code bits to AX
        sahf      ;shift condition code bits to flags
        jna SetLower ;if guess is less than num, call set lower and set lower = guess;
        ;*** else, guess > num
        fld guess ;push guess onto the stack
        fstp upper ;set upper equal to top of stack: upper = guess
        jmp whileLoop
        ;**************************

        setLower:
        fld guess   ;push guess onto stack
        fstp lower  ;store guess in lower
        jmp whileLoop

        endnewt:
        mov eax, 0
        ret

_sqrtX ENDP
END
```

C algorithm I am trying to write in Assembly:

```
double sqrtX (double x)
{
    const double ACCURACY=0.00001;
    double lower, upper, guess;
    double number;

    number = x;
    lower = 1;
    upper = number;

    while ((upper-lower) > ACCURACY)
    {
        guess = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if((guess * guess) > number)
        {
            upper = guess;
        }
        else
        {
            lower = guess;
        }
    }
    return (lower + upper)/2;
}
```

Comment: You don't balance the x87 register stack, so it overflows and `fld` produces NaN-indefinite.  Use `fsubp` and `fcomp`, or better use memory operands for your operations.  You can also use `fcomip` to set EFLAGS directly.

Comment: You could of course stop using obsolete x87 and use SSE / SSE2 with XMM regiseters for scalar FP, like compilers do by default for x86-64 and like many do even for 32-bit x86.

Comment: @Peter Cordes You were right. I cleared the stack after each loop and now it works. Thanks. Am new to assembly so didnt realize that was an issue.

Comment: x87 is weird and inconvenient (for compilers as well as humans).  There's a reason it's obsolete and replaced by SSE/SSE2 (except in rare cases where 80-bit precision is enough, but 64 isn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had stack overflow. Cleared the stack after each iteration with `finit` and now it works.

Comment: `finit` is slow, like 83 cycles on Haswell vs. 0.5 cycles for `fstp st0` to pop the stack once.  (Throughput numbers from http://agner.org/optimize/).  If you're going to bother learning x87 at all, it's much better to balance the stack properly instead of using a slow reset every iteration.  It's not a lot different from balancing pushes / pops on the call stack before a `ret`.